# How to import LaravelVuePagination library in Vue3 Script Setup

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, laravel-pagination, laravel-vue

When I try to import the library using script setup it doesn't work.

```
<script setup>
import LaravelVuePagination from "laravel-vue-pagination";
.....
<script>
```

Documentation has only included importing by **components**

```
import LaravelVuePagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';

export default {
    components: {
        'Pagination': LaravelVuePagination
    }
}
```

Well I can't use the following code in template with **script setup**

```
<Pagination
      style="page"
      :data="supplier.data"
      @pagination-change-page="pageData"
    />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code should work if you have installed it.

```
npm install laravel-vue-pagination
// or
yarn add laravel-vue-pagination
```

if it's already installed and it's not importing then you can try importing from app.js or main.js where you have initialized your Vue object.

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('alpinejs');

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from '@/App.vue'
import router from "@/routes"
import axios from 'axios'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import store from './store'
import LaravelVuePagination from 'laravel-vue-pagination';

const app = createApp(App)

app.config.globalProperties.$axios = axios;

app.component('Pagination',LaravelVuePagination);
app.use(router);
app.use(store);
app.use(Vuex);
app.mount('#app')
```

Visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-vue-pagination